# one php page with different contents and urls

Tags: php, database, singlepage

I have an xml database where are stocked several blog posts.

xml example:

```
<element id="12" size="square" category="portfolio">
    <tag tag="printer printing 3d apple iphone 5 bumper case"></tag>
    <icon class="icon-picture"></icon>
    <urlpage url="/contact/contact.html"></urlpage>
    <urlimage src='./Post thumbnail images/01.png'></urlimage>
    <date date="8 Apr"></date>
    <title>Minimal Bumper for iPhone 5 : Protect your iphone with a lightwheight and protect full case </title>
</element>
```

I want to have my website based on two main php pages. 
The main index.php page where blog post thumbnails and links are displayed.
And a single.php page where each blog posts can be displayed individually.

How can I load, change the content and url of the single.php page when I click on a blog post thumbnail link in the index.php page (finally, I think, like wordpress but without use it)?

If this is possible, how it works for SEO?

Sorry for my english, I'm french.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using GET variables which you will set in the url:

for single.php, url www.example.com.php?blog_no=121

```
if(isset($_GET["blog_no"])) {
     // connect to database and get post
}
```

You need to set $_GET variable in the url when linking to that post:
on the index.php page you would

```
<a href="single.php?blog_no=121">Post 121</a>
```

Comment: Are `$_GET` variables already set?

Comment: no you would pass them through the url for when linking to that post,  eg on index.php     <a href="single.php?blog_no=121">Post 121</a>

Comment: I think this should have been in your answer

Comment: On single.php you are checking to see if a variable has been set in the url. You can then use this variable to search the database and check for that post.

Comment: ok thank you. And if I write this url directly in the browser does it load the right content? Is it SEO friendly?

Comment: You can make it seo friendly using an htaccess to remove the .php?blog_no=  so you are left with single/121

Comment: ok. Thank you. I will try all this and ask later if I have some trouble. I'm new in php. And I was thinking it was very complicated to do this kind of things before your answere...

Comment: I succes to load the single.php file. However I have a problem to get the correct content from xml. If I set xml node from the isset variable it don't work : `if(isset($_GET["blog_no"])) {
                        
$i = $_GET["blog_no"];
$elements = new SimpleXMLElement('data.xml', null, true);

echo $i;

echo $elements->element[$i]['size'];
echo $elements->element[$i]['category']; }`

Comment: you would use the blog_no from the url to search the xml file

Comment: But I have only one xml data file. I want to search find in xml nodes...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can add in your database for each post, a field named "url", where you can define a custom url for every post.
You can use the rewrite url rule in .htaccess.
Here is a link with some pretty nice examples of how this works:
[example](http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/)

On your single.php you can load your content dynamical from your database.